# require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, apache2

Estoy haciendo unas prácticas en local con PHP y apache 2.
No soy muy experto en el funcionamiento de apache, por más que leo la documentación no encuentro solución a mi problema.

### Un poco de contexto:

Utilizo linux Mint y tengo instalado Apache, MySQL, PHP todo por defecto. También tengo el proyecto en una ruta de mi equipo y con ayuda de la terminal en el directorio y el comando `php -S localhost:4000` permito que  pueda visualizarse al buscar en el navegador: `localhost:4500`.

En las diferentes páginas utilizo`require_once` para no tener que repetir partes de codigo, lo típico.
Por ejemplo: `require_once('fragmentosPHP/header.php');` header.php contiene el codigo HTML de los metadatos de la página. Estas incrustaciones HTML funcionan perfectamente.

El problema es cuando he querido realizar mi propia librería de funciones PHP. Cuando intento cargar la librería en donde lo necesito, la página se detiene justo donde llamo a la función. Reviso la Terminal donde activé `php -S localhost:4000` y me indica:

```
127.0.0.1:33500 [500]: GET /registro.php - require_once(): Failed opening required '../../phpScripts/funciones.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home
/ProyectoBlog/fragmentosPHP/registrarUsuario/formulario_registro.php on line 1
```

Esta es la estructura del ejercicio:

[image: carpetas]

### El problema más en detalle:

Como he dicho anteriormente el problema surge cuando intento incluir las funciones.

**Este es formulario_registro.php:**
(lo de `$datosErroneos` es para poder devolver al formulario los datos erroneos del usuario)
[image: formulario_registro.php]
Nota: lo del comentario en el primer input lo he corregido ya.

**Este es el archivo con las funciones funciones.php**
[image: libreria de funciones]

**Esta es la página antes de introducir datos:**
[image: pagina web]

**Esta es la página después de rellenar con datos erróneos para validarlos y mostrar errores:**

[image: pagina desaparece]

He intentado mover todo el proyecto a  `/var/www` y tampoco sirve. He intentado relocalizar el path de php pero no lo consigo.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Buenas!

Voy a dar algunas cosas por sentadas para que quede claro la explicación:

Entiendo que en tu página web, cuando accedes a la ruta

> localhost:4000/registro.php

Lo que hace *registro.php* será incrustar el contenido de *formulario_registro.php* (que es donde tienes el formulario) y luego este *formulario_registro* llama a *funciones.php*.

Aquí es importante saber desde qué archivo estas haciendo el **include**, ya que lo que hace el include es meter el contenido de un archivo dentro del tuyo, por lo que el archivo o ruta que va a invocar los required, y en este caso, es desde registro.php ya que es el que recibe la petición.

Entonces:

```
./registro.php - include -> formulario_registro.php
./fregmentosPHP/registrarUsuario/formulario_registro.php - include -> funciones.php
./phpScripts/funciones.php // queremos hacer include de este archivo desde ./registro.php
```

Por lo que la ruta que debes poner en el include es la relativa respecto a *registro.php*

```
include './phpScripts/funciones.php';
```

Esto puede que no te sirva siempre ya que tal vez quieras llamar a formulario_registro.php desde dos archivos que no se  encuentran en la misma ruta, por lo que para solucionar esto, tendrías que obtener primero el directorio en el que te encuentras, y escribir siempre la ruta relativa al archivo. Esto se hace usando:

```
include __DIR__ . "/ruta/relativa/archivo.php";
```

[__DIR__](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) es una constante mágica de PHP que nos da el path del archivo sin "tener en cuenta" el include