# Problema rutas en PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo un problema con las rutas de un proyecto PHP (por lo que veo es algo usual). Os cuento...

Tengo un proyecto PHP con modelo MVC, es decir, tengo mis carpetas models, views y controllers, y fuera de ellas un index. Os dejo códigos y voy comentando...

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php

    require_once("controllers/controlador.php");

?>
```

MODELS\MODELO.PHP

```
<?php

    class Usuarios{

        private $db;
        private $nombre;


        public function __construct($nombre){

            require_once("models/conexion.php");
            require_once("controllers/controlador.php");
            $this->db = Conexion::conectar();
            $this->nombre = $nombre;

        }

        public function insertarUsuario(){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre) VALUES ('$this->nombre')";

            $consulta = $this->db->query($sql);

        }

    }

?>
```

CONTROLLERS\CONTROLADOR.PHP

```
<?php

    require_once("models/modelo.php");

    if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){

        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];

        $crearUsuario = new Usuarios($nombre);
        $crearUsuario->insertarUsuario();

    }

    require_once("views/vista.php");

?>
```

VIEWS\VISTA.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body>

    <h1>USUARIOS</h1>

    <form method="post" action="controllers/controlador.php">

        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"/>

        <button type="submit">Crear usuario</button>

    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

La estructura de directorios que tengo es sencilla: una raíz de donde cuelgan las tres carpetas, y el index.php en la raíz.

La cuestión es que cuando cargo el index.php todo va perfecto, llama al controlador, y este a su vez al modelo y a la vista. Como la vista aún no ha recogido datos del formulario, no instancia la clase del modelo y solo muestra el formulario a la espera de recibir datos. Ahí viene el problema.

Cuando introduzco datos en el formulario y lo envío, debería recogerlo en controlador, llamar al modelo, y ahora ya sí, instanciar la clase y lanzar el método `insertarUsuario()`. Pero, en lugar de eso, cuando introduzco datos en el formulario y lo envío, me dice que no encuentra el controlador.

No lo puedo entender, no entiendo cómo me dice que no lo encuentra si ya lo ha cargado una primera vez cuando comienza el proceso y el index.php llama al controlador

En fin, a ver si me podéis echar una manita. Estoy atascado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Veo varios errores, pero primero, porque intentas recoger nombre mediante GET si lo intentas enviar mediante POST?

Comment: Lo del POST ha sido un error mío al escribir la pregunta, he hecho ya tantas pruebas que en cuando he formulado la pregunta he copiado/pegado de varios ejemplos del código y no me he dado cuenta de ese detalle. Pero eso ya está corregido y sigo con el mismo problema.

Por favor, dime qué más fallos ves.

Muchas gracias

Comment: El otro detalle es sobre la respuesta que hizo david, es sobre las rutas si te fijas estas llamando a la ruta controllers/controlador.php pero eso no es correcto ya que deberias estar utilzando rutas relativas, no vi ningun otro detalle

Comment: Pero controllers/controlador.php es una ruta relativa, no?

Comment: Por favor, podrías poner el código con las rutas como debería ponerlas. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira esta respuesta:
[require_once(): Failed opening required](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/542334/require-once-failed-opening-required/542348#542348)

Es un caso parecido. Tienes que tener en cuenta desde qué archivo estás tratando de hacer el require.

Por lo que veo, en el HTML del formulario el atributo *action* llama a

```
./controllers/controlador.php
```

Por lo que los requires que hagas tanto en este archivo, como los que "cuelgan" de el (entiéndase cuelgan cuando un un include() dentro de otro archivo que se ha cargado vía include()) tienen que ser rutas relativas al archivo que se está ejecutando, que para tu caso, en el momento de hacer 'submit' en el formulario es ./controllers/controlador.php, por lo que la ruta debería ser relativa a esta.

Para evitar este problema debes usar rutas relativas a partir de la ruta en la que se encuentra el archivo, de la siguiente forma:

```
include __DIR__ . "/ruta/relativa/archivo.php";
```

El __DIR__ nos devuelve la ruta sin el '/' al final, por lo que el string que nosotros concatenemos debe empezar por '/'.

¡Un saludo y espero que te sirva!

Comment: He probado con la función dirname() y no lo consigo tampoco.

También he probado como ruta "../models/modelo.php" (por ejemplo), teniendo en cuenta que me dices que tengo que tomar como ruta original la que paso en el formulario de la vista, y tampoco lo consigo

Comment: Por favor, podrías poner el código con las rutas como debería ponerlas. Gracias

Comment: Prueba a hacerlo así: include_once(dirname(\_\_DIR__) . "/../models/modelo.php")

Comment: Nada, he probado pero no lo consigo. Ahora ni siquiera me carga el formulario. Lo he hecho con require_once en vez de include_once, pero imagino que esto es igual

Comment: Puedes  poner algún mensaje de error que te devuelva el PHP

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy haciendo pruebas en un equipo público y estoy utilizando el entorno online https://paiza.cloud/ que no tira errores (o al menos yo no sé verlos), pero mañana volveré a hacer pruebas desde mi equipo, con mi Xampp, e iré subiendo los errores exactos que me tire.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Vale he corregido la respuesta, efectivamente no funcionaba, no hace falta el uso de dirname(), la propia constante mágica de PHP (\_\_DIR__) ya nos devuelve la ruta a la que le tenemos que añadir la ruta relativa. Me he puesto los archivos en mi local y funciona, tienes que cambiar todos los require por: "require_once(\_\_DIR__ . '/[ruta relativa de donde se encuentra este archivo]')". No olvides la '/' al inicio de la ruta relativa

Comment: Ok, David, muchas gracias. Lo pruebo y te digo algo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo David, probado y funcionando. Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada @HugosComs! ¡Me alegro que te sirva!